# Ionic dependencias no instaladas como instalar todo de una sola vez

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, angular

necesito saber si alguien sabe como instalar todo de una sola vez, o lo tengo que hacer uno por uno.

```
npm WARN @angular/common@6.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@6.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @angular/core@5.2.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @angular/forms@5.2.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @angular/forms@5.2.10 requires a peer of @angular/common@5.2.10 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @angular/http@5.2.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@5.2.10 requires a peer of @angular/common@5.2.10 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.10 requires a peer of @angular/common@5.2.10 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @ionic-native/core@4.7.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @ionic-native/social-sharing@4.7.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @ionic-native/splash-screen@4.7.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @ionic-native/status-bar@4.7.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

    + rxjs@6.0.0
    removed 1 package, updated 1 package and audited 4669 packages in 82.479s
    found 1 low severity vulnerability
      run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en la consola introduces `npm install` e instalarás con ello todos los paquetes de librerías que tienes el package.json

Comment: Gracias!!  Solucionado!